# ruby safe way to run multiple threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a service that read all line on the file CSV then imports to the database. The process is only read the file and write to DB, no need to find or update on DB. So that I want to speed up that process by code:

```
CSV.foreach(@file.path, encoding: 'BOM|UTF-8:UTF-8', headers: true).each do |row|
  # start thread i
  Record.create(row)
  # end thread i
end
```

I want it run with multiple threads and the amount of those limits by 10 threads to keep server's RAM does not take too much.
I try with `Concurrent::FixedThreadPool`, but it sometimes loses connection from DB, event though I just set run with 5 threads

Any idea for the safe thread running?

Comment: Did you consider importing the CSV as a whole file with an import tool database instead of inserting the file line by line with Ruby?

Comment: Actually, I read from CSV then insert to collection B with some filter column. For example, age must be greater than 18 and populates in a big city

Comment: I understand, but even importing into a temporary table, then copying into the final table with some conditions and dropping the temp table should be magnitudes faster in pure SQL than in Ruby.

Comment: That's a good idea. I will apply that to the code. Furthermore, I still keep listening about safe thread solution

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Mutex

```
mutex = Mutex.new
CSV.foreach(@file.path, encoding: 'BOM|UTF-8:UTF-8', headers: true).each do |row|
  threads = Thread.new do
              mutex.synchronize do
                Record.create(row)
              end
            end 
end
threads.each(&:join)
```

I hope that helpful.

Comment: As I know the Mutex only allow 1 thread run inside the content of it per time. So it's only 1 thread running at the moment,  and others will wait until this thread jump out the content of Mutex, is it right?

Comment: Assuming the CSV file have 200 million rows, the memory it takes will be very large and it might lead to memory problem

Comment: If we use Mutex in this case, It's exactly the same with using no thread

Comment: @Peter_175: Please try Thread Pool, if you want I will create example for you. Also I am thinking in your case bulk insert is worth instead of threading.